# Hive HQL - optimizing repetitive WINDOW clause

Tags: hive, window, hql, clause

I have following HQL

```
SELECT count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY identity.hwid, passwordused.domain ORDER BY event.time ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING) pocet,
       min(event.time) OVER (PARTITION BY identity.hwid, passwordused.domain ORDER BY event.time ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING) minTime,
       max(event.time) OVER (PARTITION BY identity.hwid, passwordused.domain ORDER BY event.time ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING) maxTime 
FROM t21_pam6
```

How can I define the **3 same** WINDOW clauses into one?

The documentation (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics
) shows this example

```
SELECT a, SUM(b) OVER w
FROM T;
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY c ORDER BY d ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
```

But I don't think it's working. It's not possible to define WINDOW w as... is not a HQL command.

Comment: Just to answer your original question - it will be working if you remove the semicolon after `FROM T`. WINDOW clause is not a statement but a part of the query. Probably, there was a typo in the documentation at that moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of optimization is something that the compiler would need to do.  I don't think there is a way to ensure this programmatically.

That said, the calculation for the minimum time is totally unnecessary.  Because of the `order by`, it should be the time in the current row.  Similarly, if you can handle `null` values, then the expression can be simplified to:

```
SELECT count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY identity.hwid, passwordused.domain ORDER BY event.time ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING) pocet,
       event.time as minTime,
       lead(event.time, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY identity.hwid, passwordused.domain ORDER BY event.time) as maxTime 
FROM t21_pam6;
```

Note that the `maxtime` calculation is slightly different because it will return `NULL` for the last two values matching the conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on optimization of minTime/maxTime. From my point of view the optimization engine is working correctly and the count of map/reduce steps is OK, but I would like to make also more readable for another programmer - to extract the repetitive part into single one.

Answer (score 0):

As @sergey-khudyakov responded, there was a bug in documentation. This variant works fine:

```
  SELECT count(*) OVER w,
          min(event.time) OVER w,
          max(event.time) OVER w 
   FROM ar3.t21_pam6
   WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY identity.hwid, passwordused.domain ORDER BY      event.time ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING)
```